# Use C++ socket to validate ethernet interface configuration in QNX

Tags: c++, sockets, validation, qnx, ifconfig

I have a program that configures the ethernet interface on a remote machine running a QNX Environment, which uses `ifconfig` to assign an IP Address, netmask and default gateway.  I now need a way to determine whether the ethernet interface has a valid configuration, that I would be able to connect to remotely.

For example, giving "127.0.0.1", "255.255.255.255", or "0.0.0.0" as IP Addresses should be invalidated, because even though they are valid IP Addresses, I would not be able to establish a remote connection with these.

I need a way for a C++ application to verify that the configuration is valid and can be connected to.
I have heard that one way to do this is to try and create a socket, but I haven't had any luck so far.  I was able to create a socket with "0.0.0.0" as the IP Address just as easily as a valid one.
Maybe I'm just not doing it right.

```
int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
struct sockaddr_in ipaddr;
ipaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
inet_pton(AF_INET, "0.0.0.0", &ipaddr2.sin_addr);
bind(sock2, (struct sockaddr *) &ipaddr2, sizeof(ipaddr2));
```

Is there anything else I could do with this socket to verify connectivity?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!